# cURL not loading style/css

Tags: php, html, css, curl

So I have this pretty simple cURL code that *should* be retrieving the data of a page... Well, it actually *does* show the page's contents... **sometimes**, and also, most of the other times the style is all messed up, as the fonts aren't loading and neither do most of the images and graphic elements. The results vary if I change the URLs of the page I want to show, with some loading no problem, others not showing **anything** at all.

I guess there's a problem with how the cURL handles the css, how can I have it load it correctly?

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();

    $url = 'http://3amigos.com.mx/';

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Googlebot/2.1 (http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    echo $data;
?>
ABCDEF
```

As it is right now, sometimes it doesn't even load anything but the ABCDEF without any format, and some other times the page is completely empty.

Comment: Maybe someone knows you are forging the user agent and is blocking you.. CSS and JS unless requested with an absolute link will fail.

Comment: Curl is not a interpreter. You may can use PhantomJS is you need send http request and receive a complete website style with javascript and css interpreted.

Answer (score 2):

When you send http request with curl, curl take the response and give it to you.
If the response have a styles embedded, you can show this apply with **YOU BROWSER NOT ON/WITH CURL**.
**BUT** if the styles/resources have full URI on the attribute `src`, `href`, you can see apply this **ON YOU BROWSER NOT ON/WITH CURL**.

> **Curl is not a interpreter HTML, JS, CSS.**

Curl is only command line for transferring data using various protocols like HTTP, HTTPS, ...

You maybe need learn about [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) or [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).

**Another solution**(too slow) is get response and parse it to find all `<link>`(css style link) to open and get content and embed it...(I think this is bad idea, but work)

Comment: Aw shucks... guess it's back to the drawing board for me then. Thanks anyway.

Comment: don't worry. Please learn about PhantomJS(i really like this project). Maybe you can solved you problem with this.

Comment: I write a possible solution for you @lower see my answer

Comment: Thank you, Olaf, I'll see what I can do. Sadly, the parse approach doesn't seem too feasible as it stands right now.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this (Check the modified code):

```
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'http://3amigos.com.mx/';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Googlebot/2.1 (http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1); // Removed
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // Added
$data = curl_exec($ch);

if($data) var_dump($data);
```

The `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` is required to get the result back/returned and `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` is for the maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute. This will give you some result/text (string format) not the formatted as html.

### Here is a truncated screenshot to prove that it works:

[image]

Comment: Wait, what? I'm still shown a completely blank page when I use your code.

Comment: Did you dumped it like I did in the answer now?

Comment: I just did. However, there seems to be a problem, as not all of the data was dumped. However, this doesn't suit my needs since I need to see the actual page anyway. Thank you still.