# i have problem in my cURL script on localhost the website page not complete look capturev

Tags: javascript, php

I have problem in my cURL script on localhost the website page not complete look capturev

```html
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://morocco.blsspainvisa.com/embassy_book_appointment.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
$page=curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $page;
?>
```

On localhost the website page not complete.

Look capturev

https://ibb.co/VgHCWx1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354248/curl-not-loading-style-css

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cURL not loading style/css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354248/curl-not-loading-style-css)

Comment: **[You should not switch off `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` or `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/10/certainty-automated-cacert-pem-management-for-php-software)**. It could be a security risk! [Here is how to get the certificate bundle if your server is missing one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32095378/1839439)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the references about Css and Javascript.

cURL is not a interpreter like your browser. 
Are you try to code a phishing website, this is not good

Comment: no bro just for auto form this web site is for appointment visa